# Print Preview making Issue in C#

Tags: c#, .net, print-preview

when I click on print preview button. it shows my listed items. but when I close print preview screen and add some more items and click on print preview. it shows only that items which I enter later. I clear my old added Items.

here is my code which I'm trying

```cs
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(300, 150));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Customer Name: " + customername.Text.Trim(), new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 150));

    int yPos = 200;
    int xPos = 20;
    int brandyPos = 180;

    for (int i = numberOfItemsPrintedSoFar; i < beltlist.Count; i++)
    {
        numberOfItemsPerPage++;

        if (numberOfItemsPerPage <= 15 && count <= 3)
        {
            numberOfItemsPrintedSoFar++;

            if (numberOfItemsPrintedSoFar <= beltlist.Count)
            {

                e.Graphics.DrawString(beltlist[i].BrandName, new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(xPos, brandyPos));
                brandyPos = yPos + 20;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(beltlist[i].BeltSize.ToString() + "--" + beltlist[i].QTY.ToString(), new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, yPos));
                yPos += 20;

            }
            else
            {
                e.HasMorePages = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            yPos = 180;
            xPos += 150;
            numberOfItemsPerPage = 0;
            if (count > 3)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                xPos = 20;
                count = 1;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you reset variables like your `numberOfItemsPrintedSoFar`?

Comment: I think you need your `numberOfItemsPrintedSoFar` variable before opening the print preview again.

Comment: No BeginPrint event handler, that's probably the bug then.  Required to set numberOfItemsPrintedSoFar back to 0.

Comment: I did numberOfItemsPrintedSoFar=0;
and numberOfItemsPerPage=0;
but due to this items did'nt move on next page.